# Perl output unreadable even despite asking to encode it using UTF-8

Tags: regex, perl, encoding, utf-8, diacritics

As is apparent in the title of my question I use Perl to do some regex related query. However, I use UTF8 encoded input with diacritics in the body and when I generate an output it is always **UTF-16 LE**/**UCS-2 LE BOM** encoded.

My main problem is that the diacritics in the input are replaced with '??' in the output. I think this problem lies in the encoding. I have tried to strip a lot of the code which could have been responsible for my problem, but the problem persisted.

This is my code:

```
# Input = élèvàtòr ôpëràtör
# Output = ??l??v??t??r ??p??r??t??r

use utf8;
use open qw(:std :utf8);

    {
    while (<STDIN>)
        {
        $line = $_;

        # remove long span (), <>
        $line =~ s/[\(\)]//g;

        # remove long span [] with everything in between
        while ($line =~ s/\[[^\[\]]*\]//g) {;}
        while ($line =~ s/\<[^\<\>]*\>//g) {;}

        printf("$line");
        }
    }
```

I have changed it multiple times as to the suggestions of several other answers to similar questions here on this site:

I have tried this option:

```
use utf8;  # Source is encoded using UTF-8
use open ':std', ':encoding(locale)';
```

This resulted in my CLI stating

```
Cannot find encoding "locale" at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/open.pm line 126.
Cannot find encoding "locale" at /usr/share/perl5/core_perl/open.pm line 134.
```

I have also tried running the following options tagged at the end of my command in my CLI:

```
-CDSL -le 'print "\x{1815}"'
-CO
```

More lines I put in my code without success:

```
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8");
use open ":encoding(utf8)";
use open IN => ":encoding(utf8)", OUT => ":utf8";
```

Someone also recommended to use the

> 'environment'

but I couldn't find anything as to how I would do that. The code he suggested was:

```
export PERL_UNICODE=SDL
```

But I don't know where to put this or alter it.

I hope someone can help me with this problem.

Comment: To check the input you are receiving, can you try [this](https://pastebin.com/3WBCFtus) script? If you run it with input `élèvàtòr ôpëràtör` you should get output like this: `E9.6C.E8.76.E0.74.F2.72.20.F4.70.EB.72.E0.74.F6.72`

Comment: Cannot reproduce the problem. Do you use a perl version older than 5.16?

Comment: What OS are you using? If it is Windows then perhaps you need to change codepage `chcp 65001` to be able see utf8 output properly.

Comment: Please try the following [code](https://rextester.com/EOAZ13396) on your machine. If you use Windows 10/8/7 then in terminal window it might require to change code page `chcp 65001` to reproduce utf8 output properly.

Comment: It seems that my problem was caused by my usage of PowerShell, using bash seems to not produce the problem. Thanks for all suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

The output you showed does not appear to be UTF-16 or UCS-2 as you claim. (There are too few `?`.) There's also no evidence of a BOM.

On the other hand, the output is consistent with UTF-8. `é`, `è`, `à`, `ò`, `ô`, `ë`, `à` and `ö` all encode as two bytes using UTF-8.

Perl is doing exactly what you asked, but you are viewing UTF-8 with a tool or terminal that expects a different encoding. You need to provide the proper encoding for your tool or terminal, or adjust what your tool or terminal expects.

For example, you can tell a Windows Console to expect UTF-8 by using `chcp 65001`.

Since you provided absolutely no information about your tool or terminal, this is as far as we can help.

Comment: Thank you for looking into my question, it seems that the only thing that solved my problem was to not use PowerShell from windows but to use Bash to run my commands. Changing the code page with 'chcp 65001' unfortunately did not solve my problem in PowerShell.

Comment: `>` emits UTF-16 in PowerShell. There are ways around that. (`| Out-File filename -Encoding UTF8`)